# How correctly write toFixed() in jsx

Tags: reactjs

how to correctly write this expression to work.

```
{currency.sale.toFixed(3)}
```

[image: Scr]

Comment: Please dont paste code as image

Comment: In future, please add 1. the original code (not the image), 2. What is the issue, 3. What did you try? in your questions.

Answer (score 2):

You need to wrap whole expression inside curly braces `{}`:

```
{currency.sale.toFixed(3) / currency.sale}
```